# Как измерить угол между тремя вершинами с географическими координатами?

Tags: gps, координаты, навигация

Есть три точки, A B C заданные широтой и долготой. Как измерить угол ABC?

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет однозначный ответ. Представьте, что B и C являются [антиподами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4). В таком случае, есть бесконечное множество cамых коротких путей от точки B до точки C, поэтому угол ABC - многозначный.

Comment: @PeterOlson, если точки будут антиподами, то будет 2 ответа - `Х` (<90) и `180 - Х`. Какой из них выбрать, я уж сам решу, помогите найти Х )

Comment: Нет, там намного больше двух ответов. Если точки являются антиподами, количество ответов бесконечное. В самом деле, можно выбрать любой угол между 0 и 180, и можно найти путь с этим углом.

Comment: @PeterOlson, хорошо, положим, что это частный случай. Который, кстати, довольно редок. Как с остальными?

Comment: Взять разницу координат двух точек по долготе разделить на разницу координат тех же двух точек по широте - получите тангенс азимута. Получить два таких азимута и сложить их.

Comment: [ссылка](http://gis-lab.info/qa/aveazimuth.html) на геометрические решения подобных задач

Comment: @aleks.andr, хммм... там другая система координат. Перевести не так просто ,как может показаться, учитывая, что мы находимся на сфере, а не на окружности и наши координаты являются углами, а не расстояниями